# Java: Cached RowSet insertRow fails: SQLException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So I'm trying to understand how to use the RowSet API, specifically CachedRowSet, and I feel like I've been bashing my head against a wall for the last hour or so and could use some help.

I've got some very simple tables set up in a MySQL database that I'm using to test this. I should also add that everything I'm attempting to do with RowSet I've been able to do successfully with ResultSet, which leads me to believe that the issue is with my usage of the ResultSet API, rather than the operation I'm attempting to do itself.

Anyway, I'm trying to insert a new row using ResultSet. I'll paste my code here, then add some notes about it below:

```
CachedRowSet rowSet = null;
    try {
        RowSetFactory rsFactory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
        rowSet = rsFactory.createCachedRowSet();
        rowSet.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/van1");
        rowSet.setUsername("####");
        rowSet.setPassword("####");

        rowSet.setKeyColumns(new int[]{1});

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String query = "select * from phone";

    try {
        rowSet.setCommand(query);
        rowSet.execute();
        printTable(rowSet);

        rowSet.moveToInsertRow();

        rowSet.setInt(1, 4);
        rowSet.setString(2, "Mobile");
        rowSet.setString(3, "1");
        rowSet.setString(4, "732");
        rowSet.setString(5, "555");
        rowSet.setString(6, "1234");
        rowSet.setString(7, "");

        rowSet.insertRow();
        rowSet.moveToCurrentRow();
        rowSet.acceptChanges();
        printTable(rowSet);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So, as you can see, I'm trying to update a table of phone numbers with a new phone number. Here are the details:

1) All the phone number fields are datatype char, so that leading zeroes are not lost.

2) I'm using the default CachedRowSet implementation provided by the JDBC API, as opposed to anything specific from the MySQL driver. Not sure if that matters or not, but I'm putting it here just in case. Also, I didn't see an option to import CachedRowSet from the driver library anyway.

3) I'm setting a value for every column in the table, because the RowSet API doesn't allow for rows to be inserted without a value for every column.

4) I've tried the operation using both the setter methods and the update methods. Same result either way.

5) As far as I can tell, I'm on the insert row when executing the insertRow() method. I also return to the current row before invoking acceptChanges(), but since my code never gets that far I can't really comment on that part.

6) The exception is a SQLException (no chained exception within it) thrown on the invocation of the insertRow() method. Here is the stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Failed on insert row
at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.insertRow(Unknown Source)
at firsttry.RowSetPractice.rowSetTest(RowSetPractice.java:87)
at firsttry.RowSetPractice.main(RowSetPractice.java:20)
```

So, I'm out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated. I've searched every thread on this site I could find, all I see is stuff about it failing on the acceptChanges() method rather than insertRow().

Comment: Looking at the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/com/sun/rowset/CachedRowSetImpl.java#CachedRowSetImpl.insertRow%28%29) (Java 8), this error is thrown if your not on the insert row, or haven't set all columns, I'd double check if your `phone` table really has 7 columns, and also check the row set metadata to see which columns it thinks it has. That said, the standard rowset implementation is - IMHO - broken, and even if you manage to fix this, you'll pretty soon run into the next problem.

Comment: Taking another look at the source code; you shouldn't use `setString`, but `updateString` instead (the first doesn't update the internal `insertRow` that is used to track which columns have been set, while `updateString` does.

Comment: I'll try the update method again. I switched because I was originally trying another table and kept getting an exception with update timestamp. It would just never work (another thing that worked fine w resultset using the exact same syntax).

Comment: As for rowset problems, I keep seeing references to that, but also see posts that say its preferred over resultset for some reason. Personally I would just like to use resultset and be done with it unless I truly NEED the javabean aspect. Is that an OK practice?

Comment: I'd suggest to use normal insert and update statements unless you really have to do something else. I have yet to find a good use case for row sets myself, and I'd stay away unless you find a correct implementation. Something which `com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl` really isn't; I have run into too many different problems ranging from not following the JDBC standard with regard to the difference between `columnName` and `columnLabel`, problems with using it in auto commit (or not auto commit; the details are a bit fuzzy), to things like that difference between `setString` and `updateString`).